# Put multiple if in a switch

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I would like to put all these "if" condition with one big switch if its possible.
Soo here is my function :

```
function checkModel($model){

$model_value = 'Default Model';

if (strpos($model,'TMP') !== false) {
    $model_value = 'TMP - Default';
}
if (strpos($model,'TMT') !== false) {
    $model_value = 'TMT - Default';
}
if (strpos($model,'TMS') !== false) {
    $model_value = 'TMS - Default';
}
if (strpos($model,'IcomSpeed') !== false) {
    $model_value = 'IcomSpeed - Default';
}
if (strpos($model,'TMSSA') !== false) {
    $model_value = 'TMSSA - Default';
}
if (strpos($model,'IcomsDisplay') !== false) {
    $model_value = 'IcomsDisplay - Default';
}   
if (strpos($model,'ITV') !== false) {
    $model_value = 'ITV - Default';
}   
if (strpos($model,'Terminal') !== false) {
    $model_value = 'Terminal - Default';
}   
if (strpos($model,'IcomsTexto') !== false) {
    $model_value = 'IcomsTexto - Default';
}   
if (strpos($model,'PIV') !== false) {
    $model_value = 'PIV - Default';
}   
if (strpos($model,'TM150') !== false) {
    $model_value = 'TM150 - Default';
}   
if (strpos($model,'TM60') !== false) {
    $model_value = 'TM60 - Default';
}

return ($model_value);
};
```

I have really no idea how i can do it :/ thats why i am asking you guys ^^

Why i want to this :

Bcz with one switch i can exit directly with the "break", with this version, the program will check every "if" condition, well i think -_- ?

Now if you tell me the "if" version is faster than the "switch" version, then leave it :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switch` in Curly-brace/C-syntax languages (C, C++, C#, Java, Perl, PHP) does not support complicated operations in each `case` statement because traditionally the `switch` statement was compiled into a hashtable, which only allows immediate comparisons and does not allow for intermediate operations. PHP isn't compiled that way, but the syntax rules regarding `switch` remain.

...so in short, you cannot use `switch` in this case, however you could simplify the code by converting it to using an associative array and then iterating through it.

```
function checkModel($model){

    $arr = array(
        'TMP', 'TMT', 'TMS', 'IcomSpeed', /* etc... */
    );

    foreach ($arr as $str) {
        if( strpos($model, $str) !== false ) return $str . ' - Default';
    }

    return 'Default Model';
}
```

Comment: Thx for the explanation and I like your idea with the array ^^

Comment: Thx for taking time and write the code for me, I really appreciate. This does exactly what I want :D

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `switch` here.

What you can do is:is:

```
if (strpos($model,'TMP') !== false) {
    return 'TMP - Default';
}
```

This will make it stop as soon as the condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand how switches work you can read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

However it looks like you just want to clean up your function a bit. Although I'm by no means an expert, here's how I would do it:

```
function checkModel( $model ) {
    $strings = array( 'TMP' , 'TMT' , 'TMS' , 'IcomSpeed' , 'TMSSA' , 'IcomsDisplay' , 'ITV' , 'Terminal' , 'IcomsTexto' , 'PIV' , 'TM150' , 'TM60');
    foreach( $strings as $s ) 
        if( strpos( $model , $s ) !== FALSE )
            return $s . " - Default";
    return "Default Model";
}
```

I haven't tried to run this code.

Comment: I never used the "foreach" but I tried the same way with a normal "for" and it works great, but i still don't know if its faster or same :/

Comment: @Booba__2012 When using PHP or other interpreted languages (**unless** you have a PHP JIT or AOT compiler) you shouldn't concern yourself with micro-optimizations, just ensure your algorithms' space and computational complexities are appropriate ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory )